# QtCreator with CMake, Incorrectly parsed __cplusplus value in editor

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, qt-creator, fedora

I have a CMake project being used within QtCreator with C++17 enabled.

I can compile and use C++17 features without issues. When printing the value of `__cplusplus` I get `201703`, but when I hover over the macro in the QtCreator editor it shows a value of `1`.

Because of this, I do not get any code completion or highlighting for any C++11 (and later) features. This makes it annoying to deal with.

Standard headers such as `<memory>` have a bunch of checks like:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
// unique_ptr and shared_ptr
```

The editor disables all code under the condition due to the incorrect `__cplusplus` value.

Environment:

- Fedora 29
- CMake 3.12
- GCC 8.3.1
- QtCreator 4.7.2 (Qt 5.11.3)

Is this a known issue with QtCreator and CMake projects? Are there work arounds to get the QtCreator editor to parse the code with the correct `__cplusplus` value provided by CMake/GCC?

Comment: Interestingly, on my system QtCreator (4.9.0) does not expand this macro when hovering over it but gets the condition right. Did you check via *right click --> Find References to Symbol under Cursor* where the macro is defined and which value it has in this case?

Comment: By doing _Find Usages_ it shows: `#define __cplusplus 1` under a `<configuartion>` file. I tried to click on that, but get an error saying that the file may not exist or that I do not have the permissions to open it.

Comment: I found the tmp file for QtCreator code model inspection: _tmp/QtCreator-bhGcmE/qtc-codemodelinspection_190502_165446.txt_ : `2017969: at line 3: #define __cplusplus 1` It was categorized as an undefined macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that QtCreator 4.7.2 has a bug regarding `__cplusplus` being defined as `1`. Upgrading to 4.9.0 now correctly defines `__cplusplus` as `201703` (for C++17 Cmake project).

Answer (score 0):

Putting `#define __cplusplus 201103L` in the <project>.config file worked for me.